# Given two point $A$ and $B$, find the distance between the bounded line between $A$ and $B$ and a third point $C$

Tags: geometry

Consider this graph.

[image: The problem at hand]

This could be a wall and I want to find the distance to it. My initial thought was to simply project the position of the third point onto the line that is formed by point a and point b and calculate the distance (red line) however that is only true when the position is inside the bounds of point b and point a. What I would really want is the green line. So my question how can you find the position between the third point and those two points. Googling only shows up simple problems like finding the linear function ax+b that goes through those points and not what I need.
Furthermore, the context of this is an optimal control problem which means that the method has to be smooth. Currently, I have a circle to describe to constraint to the wall but as you can see that ends up being many circles and I would like to know if it is possible to have a smooth/continuous method of describing this distance. Furthermore, like the circle, it should not interfere with the rest of the free space like how a circle only describes the distance from its radius as opposed to a line that splits R2 in half. Furthermore, it is a predictive controller which means I cannot set the constraint when it's relevant but it has to be available as the system propagates.

Comment: You have to calculate the length of the projection from C/robot to the line through A and B (as you initially wanted to do), and calculate the 2 distances between C/robot and A and B, resp. Whichever of those 3 is the shortest represents the shortest distance from C to the line segment. If your points A and B are static and you need to calculate those distances for many C's, you can use the formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line for the distance (see also Hesse normal form).

Comment: You can also derive all of the necessary algebra yourself.  Since you know two points of the line segment, you know the equation of all points on the line.  Further, the distance from an external point to the line will be the length of the line segment from the external point to the line that is perpendicular to the line.  So, the point $~(x,y)~$ on the line will have to satisfy two constraints:  [1] It is on the line. [2] the slope of this point to the external point must be the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, once these constraints explicitly determine $~(x,y)~$ you can compute the distance from $~(x,y)~$ to the external point.